# Can I query across Multiple Servers in Aqua Data Studio?

Tags: sql, aqua-data-studio

I have multiple servers registered in Aqua-Data Studio (V16).  Is it possible to query across 2 or more servers, similar to how you can used Linked Servers in MS-SQL Server ?